# What word can I say if I want to give approximate number?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, numbers

What to say if I want to tell approximate number of something. What should I say? E.g.

> I have (around/ about/ some) 5 books.

Is there a rule for number approximation?

Comment: Related: ["Where did the odd in N odd years come from?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18966/where-did-the-odd-in-n-odd-years-come-from)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some alternatives, depending on the context, situation and use. I provided an example for each of them (taken from the NOAD):

> - **Circa** (often preceding a date: *built circa 1935*);
> - **Approximately** (*there are approximately 24 children per classroom*);
> - **Around** (*software costs would be around $1,500*);
> - **About** (*reduced by about 5 percent*);
> - **Roughly** (*this is a walk of roughly 13 miles*);
> - **Something like** (*there were something like fifty applications*);
> - **Of the order of** (*sales increases are of the order of 20%*);
> - **More or less** (*more or less symmetrical*).

So, in your case, I'd use **approximately**, **about** or **something like** (choose accordingly to your situation, i.e. formal vs informal, written vs oral, etc.)

Comment: Which dictionary?

Comment: The one built-in my system, why?

Comment: Because it seems nicer to give credit for the examples than to use them without credit.

Comment: I usually give credit (as you could see from my other answers), but I can't put a link to a program in my computer, obviously.

Comment: @Alennano: Your dictionary is the NOAD. It's built into most Macs.

Comment: @Alenanno: You can link to definitions [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/) that will match your built-in dictionary.

Comment: @Callithumpian: Thanks for the link! I checked it, but they have less info compared to the one I have... Maybe it's not updated?

Answer (score 2):

- **About**: fine.
- **Around**: fine, slightly informal with objects (discrete things). This is perhaps best used with larger numbers or hours / abstract quantities: *it will begin around six o'clock*.
- **Roughly**: fine, but you would probably not use this with lower numbers; it implies that you've made an estimate.
- **Approximately**: very formal; usually a shorter word is better.
- **Some**: very informal in this sense; usually inadvisable in writing.

Answer (score 1):

Purely commentary on what others have written:

If you're speaking informally, **about** and **around** are the best:
- I have around 5 books.
- I have about 5 books.
(I can't think of any contexts to distinguish them; they feel pretty similar)

**Roughly** works too by it feels like the answer was meant o give an exact number but you just don't know.

**Some** has a jaunty (and therefore not common) feel. "There are some 500 live cobra in the with the stolen bank vault, said the henchman"

**Approximately** is more technical sounding (a more formal version of 'roughly').

**Something like** is nicely informal (colloquial and common)

**Circa** is very academic sounding and usually used with dates (anything else is very formal sounding).

---

*Edit:* I just heard on national news an announcer say "some 300 deaths", so I think our impression that 'some' is informal is totally wrong. It's not overly formal, just acceptable in news.