# Why do we say "odd" when describing numbers?

Tags: etymology, numbers, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the “odd” in “N odd years” come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18966/where-did-the-odd-in-n-odd-years-come-from)

When we speak about numbers, we usually associate "odd" with it. For example, "We have 70-odd people working for our company". Why the word "odd"? Clearly, it is not associated with the odd/even value of the number it is describing. What's the etymology of it?